# Consider a normal population with mean = −3456 and variance = 3. Consider a random sample of size 11. Let S^2 denote sample variance. Calculate E[S^6]

Tags: statistics

In this question, I converted $E(S^6) = E((S^2)^3)$. After this, I simply converted $S^2$ to $\sum_{i=0}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2/(n - 1)$, but I can't seem to find a way to solve after that. Any hints on how this might be solved?

Comment: Typo: In the summation, i = 1, not 0

Comment: You can ignore the mean of the underlying distribution and treat its variance as the square of its scale, so it will be $27$ times the answer for a standard normal.  Note that if $Y\sim N(0,1)$ then $E[Y^2]=1$, $E[Y^4]=3$, $E[Y^6]=15$ and you can expand $E[(S^2)^3]$

Comment: @Henry I am not really sure I quite get it..

Comment: I am suggesting you deal with a standard normal, expand $(S^2)^3$ (which may be a bit of a mess), take the expectations, and finally multiply by $27$